# how to convert JSON response to String and compare it with string

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to get the POST data of a request and compare it with the expected data string but it does not work, not sure what is going wrong here :

```
var PostData = '"{\\\"filter\\\":{\\\"operator\\\":\\\"and\\\"}}"';  
var message = JSON.parse(element.message).message;   
expect(PostData).toMatch(JSON.stringify(message.params.request.postData));
```

My Expect fails every time with this error :

```
Expected '"{\"filter\":{\"operator\":\"and\"}}"' to match '"{\"filter\":{\"operator\":\"and\"}}"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

`expect(PostData).toMatch(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(message.params.request.postData)));`

or

````
var PostData = JSON.stringfy(...put the text here...)
expect(PostData).toMatch(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(message.params.request.postData)));```
````

Comment: let me correct my question var message = JSON.parse(element.message).message;

Comment: try setup your Post data like ```var PostData = JSON.stringfy(...put the text here...)```

Comment: What is the npm library that you're using? I want to simulate here.. Also, Can you try to use .toBeequals, or something related.. toMatch could have his particularities

Comment: I can not use .toBe() or .toBeeual() as I would like to match just part of the response string.

Answer (score 0):

Use .toBe() instead of .toMatch()